# How to determine the state of an email - Read mode / Compose Mode / Reply Mode from Office.context.mailbox.item

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

Is there a way to determine the current state of an email? Is the email currently read / composed or replied to from inside an Outlook app?

I could not find any method in `Office.context.mailbox.item` which can point out the state of the email.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there's no property that specifies the state.  You can try reading the value of the sender or internetMessageId properties; if they have a value then it's read mode, otherwise it's compose mode.

Comment: I just came across this requirement recently, and still nothing in the API, AFAIK. I'm glad you commented because I thought there was no real way and I forgot my own answer from three years ago!!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to believe. Whoever designed the API might have had his reasons for that, I think he was wrong though...

**Solution 1:**

Do like Eric says. Check if the sender has an ID. If not, your composing. I don't really like this solution. You're depending on the internal current state of the API.

**Solution 2:**

Inject the mode(compose/read) through your entry point.

- For commands make 2 commands, one for each mode.
- If you are using a taskpane set the entry url to `<your-url>/taskpane.html?mode=compose/read` in your `manifest.xml` depending on the `ExtensionPoint`. Then just extract the value inside of your webapp.